# Flutter setstate on local variable not updating UI

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, setstate

So I tried to dynamically update an individual listview item. I am using a function to generate each item and I created a local variable in that function. I used setstate to update that variable but the UI is not updating. If i make the same variable global it works but i changes every listview items which I dont want. Does anyone have any tips on doing that? I am new to flutter and Sorry if this has been asked multiple times. I tried searching but couldnt find any solutions. This is a similar code for the item builder function.

```
Widget generateListItem(){ 
    bool flag= false;
    return InkWell(
       onTap:(){
          setState((){
             flag=true;
          })
       },
       child: Text(flag? "Changed" : "Not Changed"),
    );
}
```

Comment: When rebuild 'generateListItem' by setState(), flag is also reset. So always flag is false.

Comment: Ohh.. That makes more sense now. Is there any way to update the item individually?

Comment: Make it a variable inside the `State` class instead of inside the method. @Bikramgurung

Comment: If I do that setstate changes every Item. I want to individually change the specific item.

Comment: You need to control that value at top parent widget re-builded. "Page(here)[Stateful widget] - build() - 'generateListItem' widget..."

Comment: Please show me your page source.

Comment: Umm.. sorry for the trouble.. I figured it out after your explanation @KuKu. I created an object for child item and changed its variable. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

the flag is resetted every time you call setState, beacuse the flag is in your generateListItem() widget,

I think you must set the bool in a list, so when you called setState, the state in the list of bool not resetted,

```
List<bool> flag = [];  // 

Widget generateListItem(int i){ 
flag.add(false);
return InkWell(
   onTap:(){
      setState((){
         flag[i]=true;
      })
   },
   child: Text(flag[i]? "Changed" : "Not Changed"),
);}
```

Comment: amazing! `Map<String,bool>` could be too.